# Git получить все коммиты с изменёнными файлами

Tags: git

Есть вот такая команда:

```
git log --pretty=format:'{ %n "commit": "%H",%n "subject": "%s",%n "commiter": {%n    "name": "%cN",%n    "email": "%cE",%n    "date": "%cD"%n  }%n}'
```

Выводит все коммиты в виде JSON, но вывести еще и файлы, которые были изменены в коммите, никак не получается

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11094170

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, в формате нельзя получить список файлов